# Reactively change the id of a picture being displayed in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs

Based on the useres input, I want to display the coresponding image. Theoretically *if* or *chase switch* work, however I was hoping for a more ellegant solution, as there are over 100 files to chose from. My idea was to use  `shinyjs::show(id = "corresponding id")` instead. However, I can't figure out a way to access the id based on the users input.

Here is a short sample of the code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(sodium)
library(readxl)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

## one picture as example
img(id="33", height = 315, width = 560, src = "T33.png"),

## get user input
numericInput("num", "chose value:", value = NULL, min=1, max = 3),

## confrim selection
actionButton("ok", "OK")

)
```

Based on the user input the program will perform some calculations and then return the corresponding picture. All the pictures are hidden to begin with, using  `shinyjs::show(id = "...")`.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

startNum<- 33
number <- reactiveValues()

observeEvent(input$ok,{
        
## I'm creating a random reactive variable here, which is part of the game
           number$n1 <- sample(c(1:3), size = 1, replace = T)

## find the picture to be displayed depending on starting number, user input and random variable

m <- startNum - input$num - number$n1

## now display the picture. this part is **not working**
                          
           shinyjs::show(id = "m")
           
           
        })

}
```

I also tried to reactively access the id using something along the lines of input$id, which I couldn't get to work either. Would be very thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: Try `m <- paste0(startNum - input$num - number$n1)`, and then `shinyjs::show(id = m)`

Comment: works perfect! thank you!